# Infinitiy NumberFormatException when creating BigDecimal

Tags: java, android

I have a function that formats a float value into USD currency format, but when the values are fractions of a dollar they get formatted to the last two non-zero decimals.

```
public static String currency(float number) {

    NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    currencyFormatter.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("USD"));

    String[] floatParts = new BigDecimal(number).toPlainString().split("\\.");

    if(number < 1 && floatParts.length == 2) {

        String decimalPortion = floatParts[1];
        int numDecimalPlaces = 0;
        while (decimalPortion.charAt(numDecimalPlaces) == '0')
            numDecimalPlaces++;

        if(numDecimalPlaces > 2)
            currencyFormatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(numDecimalPlaces + 2);
        else
            currencyFormatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

    } else {
        currencyFormatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    }

    return currencyFormatter.format(number);
}
```

I'm using Firebase Crashlytics and I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException, Infinity or NaN: Infinity, exception at:

    String[] floatParts = new BigDecimal(number).toPlainString().split("\\.");
```

What is causing this excpetion? If a non-numerical value was passed to this function, wouldn't the exception occur prior to reaching this line of code?

EDIT

The calling method:

```
@SerializedName("current_price")
@Expose
@ColumnInfo(name = "current_price")
private float currentPrice;

public void setCurrentPrice(float currentPrice) {

    if(currentPrice < 0.0001) {
        priceName = "$" + NumberFormatter.roundToLastDecimalDigits(currentPrice, 3);
    } else {
        priceName = NumberFormatter.currency(currentPrice);
    }

    this.currentPrice = currentPrice;
}
```

Comment: "*If a non-numerical value was passed to this function, wouldn't the exception occur prior to reaching this line of code?*" -> NO, at least not if `number` is `NaN` or a `Infinity`, as suggested by the exception; because `number` is never used before that line in posted code

Comment: When or how is a value Infinity? I have a vague recollection of NaN from my System Programming class, I think something to do with dividing zero, but what about infinity?

Comment: `number = Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY` or `number = 1f/0`; `Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` or `-1f/0`; `Float.NaN` or `0f/0`  (obviously `10f/0` [or any other positive float divided by zero] is also `POSITIVE_INFINITY`)  || the calling of that method is not posted, so we cannot see what argument is passed, where it comes from

Comment: Give an example input that results in this exception.

Comment: The calling of that method occurs when Retrofit uses GSON to serialize an object, which is why I'm having a hard time understanding why I'm getting this exception only occasionally from some of my users. The values coming from the API are only numbers.

Comment: maybe GSON uses `NaN` to indicate a *wrong* / *invalid* number? eventually use `Float.isFinite(number)` to test for valid number (not `NaN` neither infinity)